# ClearDb User Privileges

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench

So, I have a heroku server with the cleardb (ignite) add-on. I found my endpoints for the database, and setup a host. I then used MySQL Workbench to connect to the DB, so I used the endpoints and it logged me in, but then, while writing a zend api, I added the login creds to the application.ini, I ran the server and it turns out I got a Access Denied for the user. I went back to MySQL Workbench and found out that my username has no privileges, I then looked to the internet for help, and after 5 hours of searching I still cant get privileges. I tried to login with root, but it requires a password, am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same issue, check:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95335/cleardb-granting-created-user-access

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ClearDB does not support execution functions with SUPER privileges.

More on that you can find here: [Create function without SUPER privileges](https://web.archive.org/web/20201029200142/https://getsatisfaction.com/cleardb/topics/create_function_without_super_privileges).

> The reason you're running into this issue is because of the replication configuration that we use in our clusters and the fact that you're on a multi-tenant cluster, however it's not ClearDB specific (the message you received came from MySQL itself). We do not alter any MySQL code in any way, and use the same binaries that are able to be downloaded from MySQL's website.

> We offer complete support for providing SUPER privileges on our dedicated clusters so that you can create UDFs, stored procedures and triggers. You can read more about our dedicated clusters by going to our pricing page (please scroll to the bottom of the page): https://www.cleardb.com/pricing.view.

Answer (score 1):

ClearDB provides a sub-user for using database operations. If you want to perform some operations then you have to create other users expect of DBA.